# Can't debug aspnetcore app in VSCode 1.55.1 on Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm unable to debug my aspnetcore app in VSCore on Mac.

When I hit "Start Debugging", it doesn't start the web server.

At that point the web server is not running and there is nothing to debug.

I have tried reinstalling VS Code, as well as recreating the Web csproj from scratch. Neither of those helped.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this out, after considerable digging. It turns out VSCode debugging doesn't work on Mac OS 11.1 on Apple Silicon (M1).

I upgraded to the latest Mac OS and now it works fine. :)